# Concat two table columns and update one with result

Tags: sql, merge, concatenation

I have table that has two columns and I need to concatenate these two and update first column with result.
For example assume this is my table:

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | col1  | col2  |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | text1 | text2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  2 | text3 | text4 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

after concatenation my table should be:

```
+----+-------------+-------+
| id |    col1     | col2  |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 | text1.text2 | text2 |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  2 | text3.text4 | text4 |
+----+-------------+-------+
```

How can I do this using SQL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this (for MySQL)

```
UPDATE your_table
SET col1 = CONCAT_WS('.', col1, col2)
```

and this for MS-SQL

```
UPDATE your_table
SET col1 =col1 || "." || col2
```

Answer (score 4):

Homeworks?

I asume mysql:

```
update table t
set col1 = concat( col1, '.', col2)
```

Comment: No it's not a homework! I created my table and after inserting lots of data I understood two columns should be stored together. Thanks

Comment: Even if it was homework... this is what a developer does anyhow... 30% time on Google, 30% on SO, 30% implementing, 10% responding to comments on why it isn't homework.

Comment: @Armstrongest , you miss 5% drinking coffe. We are in touch. Thanks about your comment.

Comment: @danihp Only 5% drinking coffee?? You lucky b!! ;)

Answer (score 4):

with MS SQL Server 2014 
I used it like this

```
UPDATE CANDIDATES 
SET NEW_ADDRESS_EN = CANDI_HOME_NO + ', ' + 
CANDI_VILLAGE + ', ' + CANDI_ROAD + ' Road, ' + CANDI_PROVINCE
```